# CMake RequireAdministrator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, cmake

I'm trying to set the RequireAdministrator manifest flag on an executable I'm building with CMake and Visual Studio.

Any ideas on how to direct CMake to set that option?

Thanks!

Billy3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(your_executable PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS    "/MANIFESTUAC:\"level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'\" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")
```

Comment: Works so long as remove /SUBSYSTEM:Windows ... it's a console app :)

Comment: Note that these manifest settings don't seem to show up in the project properties, but they do appear in the intermediate manifest.  And they are recorded in the .vcproj file.  (This is with VS2008).

Answer (score 13):

I appreciate that the question is tagged visual-studio-2008, but for VS2010 this produces the following error message:

> error MSB4030: "level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'" is an invalid value for the "UACUIAccess" parameter of the "Link" task. The "UACUIAccess" parameter is of type "System.Boolean".

An equivalent CMake command (disregarding the /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS portion) for VS2010 is

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(your_executable PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/level='requireAdministrator' /uiAccess='false'")
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a console app, you need to remove the "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS".

try this:

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS " /MANIFESTUAC:\"level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'\" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

With cmake 3.24.2 it works well with:

```
target_link_options(<target name> PRIVATE "/MANIFESTUAC:level='requireAdministrator'" PRIVATE "/MANIFESTUAC:uiAccess='false'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on what Fraser said, the command that worked for me in cmake 3.9.1 and Visual Studio 10 is:

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(your_executable PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/MANIFESTUAC: /level='requireAdministrator' /uiAccess='false'")
```