# How to get Administrator privilege with cmake in windows application?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I want to build a window application that needs administrator privileges with CMake .
I try add  "/MANIFESTUAC:\"level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'\" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS" , but it not work

Environment: Windows10

IDE: VS2017

CMAKE : default with VS2017,version  3.12.18081601-MSVC_2

```
add_executable(MSP_D WIN32 ${MSP_D_SRC} msp_d.rc)

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(MSP_D PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS    "/MANIFESTUAC:\"level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'\" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")
```

How to solve this ?How to get my purpose?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Running cmake to generate build scripts or building an application from source does not typically require admin privileges.    If the application, once built, requires admin access, then it needs to be installed or run by a user/process with needed privileges.  That generally means you will need help from someone with admin privileges, or have access (e.g. knowledge of username and password) for a privileged account.   If a non-privileged user was able to bypass that need, there would be little point in system security.

Comment: @Peter yep, I know that . But I want use this application to add HTTPS Certification, so it need   admin privileges. Would you please  help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You add your executable with the name `MSP_D` but try so set the target properties on `your_executable` which obviously can't work. The line for the properties should be `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(MSP_D PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS    "/MANIFESTUAC:\"level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'\" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")`.

Comment: @GSIO01 I  know , it was my edit error. But actually it was MSP_D not your_executable. And with MSP_D, it not work.

Comment: See if this works. SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(MSP PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/MANIFESTUAC:\"level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'\" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")

Comment: @vainman I see. Is your application actually a GUI-application or a console application? In the second case the `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` should be removed. Also it seems that there were [some changes from VS2008 to VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9070303/5778928).

Comment: @SolidMercury you can add your comment as an answer, I tried and it definitely works, thanks!

Comment: @Peter The need here is to signal that the application requires uac elevation from the user to run. On windows this is separate from and will not be achieved by running as administrator. It is a linker flag to the executable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use something like this. You may need to change subsystem based on your project type.

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(MSP PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/MANIFESTUAC:\"level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'\" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")
```