# CMake: How to Set Administrator Privileges and Fix Linking Errors with C++20

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I am a complete CMake newbe and I am currently trying out SDL2 with CMake and CPP version 20. I always wondered how do I require Administrator when executing the Application. I searched through Stackoverflow and found a possible solution:

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(quizee PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/MANIFESTUAC:\"level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'\" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")
```

This is my complete CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(quizee)
Include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
        SDL2
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libsdl-org/sdl
        GIT_TAG release-2.28.x
        GIT_SHALLOW TRUE)

if(NOT SDL2_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(SDL2)
    add_subdirectory(${sdl2_SOURCE_DIR} ${sdl2_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
endif()


FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SDL2)

add_subdirectory(extern/glad)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(quizee main.cpp)


SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(quizee PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/MANIFESTUAC:\"level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'\" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")

#Set SDL include directory for quizee
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${SDL2_SOURCE_DIR}/include extern/glad/include)

#Set SDL library directory for quizee
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${SDL2_BINARY_DIR})

#link to SDL2 statically for quizee
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE SDL2-static glad )
```

When I build my project I get a linking error. I am on Windows and use CLion

```
C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\CLion\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\Users\chris\CLionProjects\quizee\cmake-build-debug --target quizee -j 14
[1/1] Linking CXX executable quizee.exe
FAILED: quizee.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\CLion\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe -g /MANIFESTUAC:"level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS CMakeFiles/quizee.dir/main.cpp.obj -o quizee.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libquizee.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 -LC:/Users/chris/CLionProjects/quizee/cmake-build-debug/_deps/sdl2-build _deps/sdl2-build/libSDL2d.a  extern/glad/libglad.a  -lm  -lkernel32  -luser32  -lgdi32  -lwinmm  -limm32  -lole32  -loleaut32  -lversion  -luuid  -ladvapi32  -lsetupapi  -lshell32  -ldinput8  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\CLion\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find /MANIFESTUAC:level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false': No such file or directory
C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\CLion\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Is anyone kind enough to help me with this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what tool accept those parameters, but GCC does not. Not to mention the quotes within quotes problem. Have you perhaps read some documentation for MSVC instead of GCC?

Comment: You mention a solution you found on SO. It would help if you added a link, this would allow others to verify it.

Comment: @Friedrich here is a link of the stackoverflow question I found.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56805006/how-to-get-administrator-privilege-with-cmake-in-windows-application)

Comment: You can't acquire administrative privileges while building your code. That's something that can only be granted when *running* your code.

Comment: Okay this does make sens to me . How would I do that?